# Powershell select where not in

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script where I select all the values (they are numeric) from the column of a tab in an Excel sheet. It works but I want to exclude numbers that are returned from a select from an Oracle table. For the moment I just want to get the select "where not in" functioning, I will worry about putting the values I want excluded into an array later.
My Powershell select is below

```
$Table = "Inventory Parts$"
$qry = "select [Part No] from [{0}]" -f $Table;
$cmd.CommandText = $qry;
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd;
$dt = new-object System.Data.dataTable("$($Table)");
$null = $da.fill($dt);
```

I select from the tab (Inventory Parts) and assign it to a data table. How do I put in "where not in" to the select? If I could just have an array hardcoded with values and use that as the values for "where not in" it would be start. After that I will instead populate the array from the Oracle table.
Thank you for any replies.

Edit:
I have got as far as populating an array with the values I want in the "where not in" clause (see below).

```
$queryString = "select PART_NO  from INVENTORY_PART_CFV WHERE PART_NO like 
'100009%'   "

   $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList


   $command = new-Object 
    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($queryString, $connection)

  $connection.Open()


  $rdr = $command.ExecuteReader();

  Foreach($row in $rdr)

   {


  $array.add(  $row.Item("PART_NO") ) 

   }
```

They go into the array "$array" but I need to append this on to my select statement

```
 "select PART_NO  from INVENTORY_PART_CFV WHERE PART_NO NOT IN " + $array
```

I don't know how to do this though.

Comment: i suspect i am misunderstanding your question - you have outlined the code in your text. [*grin*] in any case, use `$Collection | Where-Object {$_ -notin $ExcludeList}` to fiter out the unwanted items.

Comment: this seems to be a question about sql query syntax - this should help you - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: I will try Lee_Daily's code in the morning, thank you.

Comment: You are after `SELECT [Your Column] FROM [Table] WHERE [Column] NOT IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'etc')`. This is the SQL command, Lee has provided you the PowerShell filter version. I would recommend trying to filter as close to the source as possible to speed up commands and such.

Comment: I have edited my original question.